# How does the java compiler assign index's in the local variables table?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, bytecode

Alright so I'm writing a compiler and I'm trying to use the information in the local variables table to figure out names/types for variables.

I have the following code:

```
public void noob() {
    try {
        int hello = 0;
        short yo = 1;
        byte y = 2;
        int[] e = new int[9];

        System.out.println(y + ", " + hello + ", " + yo+", "+e);

    } catch (Exception var6) {
        var6.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When reading the variables table I get the following:

```
LocalVariable{uid=-1, start=0, end=69, nameIndex=30, typeIndex=31, varIndex=0, name='this', typeName='LMain;'}
LocalVariable{uid=-1, start=2, end=60, nameIndex=37, typeIndex=18, varIndex=1, name='hello', typeName='I'}
LocalVariable{uid=-1, start=4, end=60, nameIndex=38, typeIndex=39, varIndex=2, name='yo', typeName='S'}
LocalVariable{uid=-1, start=6, end=60, nameIndex=40, typeIndex=41, varIndex=3, name='y', typeName='B'}
LocalVariable{uid=-1, start=12, end=60, nameIndex=42, typeIndex=43, varIndex=4, name='e', typeName='[I'}
LocalVariable{uid=-1, start=64, end=68, nameIndex=44, typeIndex=45, varIndex=1, name='var6', typeName='Ljava/lang/Exception;'}
```

(ignore the uid column).

I noticed that varIndex is not unqiue for every variable. Why do `hello (int)` and `var6(Exception)` share the same varIndex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is smart enough to reuse variable slots for variables whose scopes do not overlap.  Because they can never both be used at the same time, there is no need to store them separately.

Since `hello` and `var6` have no overlap, the slot can be reused.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Is their anything that will be unique to every variable? such as nameIndex, typeIndex?

Comment: @JonathanBeaudoin: Probably not.  TypeIndex would certainly not be unique, since variables can have the same type.  Try making two variables with the same name in different scopes and look at nameIndex.

Comment: Nope it reuses that too. Okay I guess I will have to find another way to make a unique id. Regardless, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jonathan Beaudoin: what is the purpose of the unique id you want to create?